# Excel specific cell conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I am trying to format a whole column (A1:A100) based on the values on each row.

For example: If A1 > 0, then cell should be red
             If A2 < 0, then cell cell should be green 
And so on for each single cell on that column.

I know it should be something like an IF/THEN formula but I have no clue about how to do it. = IF(A1:A100)>0Then red, Or IF(A1:A100)>0Then green.. this one is clearly not working.

I could rally use some help here. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is a conditional formatting button on the ribbon's home tab.
You can set virtually any kind of condition and any behaviour regarding cell appearance there.

Here is a quick overview: http://www.contextures.com/xlCondFormat01.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a formula for this. Just select cells A1:A100, on the Home tab, Styles group, click Conditional Formatting, then either the **Greater than**, or **Less than** option - there are others as you can see.

Type 0 in the dialog that appears and click the drop-down to choose your formatting; click Custom Format.. if you want to build your own.

If you build a few rules for the same range then from the Conditional Formatting options, choose Manage Rules. From here you can change the order of them, delete, and choose to **Stop If True** (if appropriate).

If in the future you wish to use a formula then you would highlight the range A1:A100 and the formula would just be `=A1<0`. That is, it only needs to refer to the first cell in the range. To use a formula you would choose **New Rule** and click the option to "Use a formula.." (again, having selected the range beforehand).

[image]